# Nothing Being Passed via $_Post to Php from login code?

Tags: android

I've been working on a log-in/register for an android app and have the register up and running but the log-in doesnt seem to be passing anything over to the php script via post like the register was? , I'm pretty sure the php script is fully functional as I've tested it with Postman, If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated, Cheers

```
public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {


private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL="http://192.168.0.17/WebD/HASSAPP/login.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public LoginRequest(String username,String password , Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);

    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("username",username);
    params.put("password",password);
}

@Override
public Map<String,String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

}

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);//Edit to change title text
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);

    bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success) {
                            String businessname = jsonResponse.getString("businessname");
                            String username = jsonResponse.getString("username");

                            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("businessname", businessname);
                            intent.putExtra("username", username);
                            Login.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };


            LoginRequest loginrequest = new LoginRequest(username,password,responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Login.this);
            queue.add(loginrequest);

        }
    });
}
```

I cannot understand how me sending via Post on my register is working fine but On Log-in it's non responsive , Log-in button does nothing , not even send me to mainactivity like the intent's purpose,
Kind Regards,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

This overriden method should be protected. You have it as public.

```
@Override
 protected Map<String,String> getParams() {
    return params;
 }
```

Also, for debugging purposes, you might want to override the error listener as well.